# How to access a fusion drive from ubuntu linux by mounting apple core storage

Tags: partition, unix, kernel-panic, fusion-drive

my iMac with 3TB fusion drive won't boot anymore. even when booting to recovery it crashes with kernel panic. the stack trace says

`com.apple.driver.Corestorage 
 dependency com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily`

the mac also won't start from recovery mode because kernel panic occurs. I hoped I could fix the file system from the recovery mode.

As it happens my backup is not up to date so I thought I start a linux live system and try to mount the device or even fix the file system. or in the worst case just recover some files.

Fdisk tells me:

[image: fdisk output]

I have no success following this https://superuser.com/questions/961401/mounting-hfs-partition-on-arch-linux/1088110#1088110 tutorial also I have tried [hfsexplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/). While I can access /dev/sda3 and /dev/sdb3 I have no success with /dev/sdb2 or /dev/sda2. it tells me that the type is unknown. also listing the partitions with gparted tells me the file system type is unknown.

I assume that the disk has no hardware issue. According to smartctl I get:
[image]

so how can I go on from here? Is it safe to say the file system is broke? Can I fix it? can I somehow mount this Apple Core Storage system?

Comment: If your macOS installation is at all up to date, it's increasingly likely that the volume(s) you can't mount are not HFS, but APFS. A quick Google search seems to indicate that can be mounted too on Linux, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: according to this discussion: https://askubuntu.com/questions/991695/is-it-possible-to-mount-apfs-apples-newest-file-system-in-ubuntu-17-10 it will be difficult. However this tutorial http://az4n6.blogspot.de/2018/01/mounting-apfs-image-in-linux.html I have successfully installed apfs-fuse but I can't mount the device not with the method from the tutorial and not directly. I always get the error "Unable to get Volume" if using the loop method from the tutorial I also some nids which where not found. I will continue to try and keep u updated

Comment: just added an issue to apfs-fuse c.f.: https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse/issues/27

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this?